# Where's is defensive strike in the Compendium?

Tags: dnd-4e

We built our very first D&D characters based off of the new Red Box.  I rolled a halfling rogue, one of the at-will abilities I have is Defensive Strike. This week I signed up for the compendium and I can't find Defensive Strike in there at at all.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or is it just not there?

Answer (score 7):

**It isn't there.**

In theory, the *Red Box* characters should be able to transition directly classes from *Heroes of the Fallen Land*.  In practice, several things got changed.

The Thief was among the worst.  The thief as presented in Heroes of the Fallen Lands uses a basic attack augmented by various class powers and benefits instead of At-Will attacks.

I recommend rebuilding your character via the compendium.  If you like using At-wills, then go with the Rogue from the Player's Handbook.  There is nothing overly comparable to Defensive Strike though.  Otherwise, the Thief is just fine, there is one in my campaign now and he does quite a bit of damage!

IMHO, your questions shows that Wizards of the Coast did not adequately plan the relaunch of the 4e line with the Red Box and Essentials.  There should be no differences in the classes as presented by the two products.

Comment: Pat I was mostly wanting to using some of the 3rd party tools that access the compendium and import my power cards, power cards that were included in the Red Box. It's very strange, the Compendium makes it seem as though the contents of the Red Box are available, however this card, as well as some others that I can't remember off the top of my head, are missing.

Answer (score 1):

As I look through the Red Box power cards as we speak, I do see the At-Will 'Defensive Strike'. Now, while WOTC may have made an oversight and not placed it in the compendium I highly doubt that you have anything to worry about unless you see an errata for such power.

I think that when **Heroes of the Fallen Lands** came out WOTC decided not to use At-Will's for martial characters, but I don't use the Compendium so I can't direct you were to look but what I can suggest is that if WOTC has never given an official errata for the power, then it still exist as a legal option for the appropriate rogue build.

Comment: Thanks Caden. Again, I'm not worried about not having a legal option, I'm disappointed that the card isn't available in the compendium and I have to manually add it to the third party tool I'm using.